# Android M FingerPrint Security

Tags: android, fingerprint

I have found no document that indicates :
 - whether the fingerprint are stored ( in a secure place : like Apple in a chip ?  -  if google grantee that  FingerPrints are not tracked. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry but English is needed if you want to have a good chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google give info in this post: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html

> The Android Fingerprint API protects user privacy by keeping users’
>   fingerprint features carefully contained within secure hardware on the
>   device. This guards against malicious actors, ensuring that users can
>   safely use their fingerprint, even in untrusted applications.

Answer (score 3):

As per the android documentation,the fingerprint scanner needs a Cipher object and a key which is generated using the android's Key generator class which makes it even more secure also they are stored safely in android's key store , which ensures a very high level of security.